# Get Percent change where axis equals columns in python pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I have the following dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
w = pd.Series(['EY', 'EY', 'EY', 'KPMG', 'KPMG', 'KPMG', 'BAIN', 'BAIN', 'BAIN'])
x = pd.Series([2020,2019,2018,2020,2019,2018,2020,2019,2018])
y = pd.Series([100000, 500000, 1000000, 50000, 100000, 40000, 1000, 500, 4000])
z = pd.Series([10000, 10000, 20000, 25000, 50000, 10000, 100000, 50500, 120000])
df = pd.DataFrame({'consultant': w, 'fiscal_year':x, 'actual_cost':y, 'budgeted_cost':z})

indexer_consultant_fy = ['consultant', 'fiscal_year']
df = df.set_index(indexer_consultant_fy).sort_index(ascending=True)
df['actual_budget_pct_diff'] = df.pct_change(axis='columns',fill_method='ffill')['budgeted_cost']
```

How can I get actual_cost and budgeted_cost to switch within the last line of code without switching the columns in the dataframe?

The result should that be when the actual_cost is higher than the **budgeted_cost** the **actual_budget_pct_diff** will be a **positive number**? Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As what you want is just to compute the pct_change between 2 columns, you can do it *by hand*, as it it will still be vectorized:

```
df['actual_budget_pct_diff'] = (df.actual_cost-df.budgeted_cost)/df.budgeted_cost
```

You get:

```
                        actual_cost  budgeted_cost  actual_budget_pct_diff
consultant fiscal_year                                                    
BAIN       2018                4000         120000               -0.966667
           2019                 500          50500               -0.990099
           2020                1000         100000               -0.990000
EY         2018             1000000          20000               49.000000
           2019              500000          10000               49.000000
           2020              100000          10000                9.000000
KPMG       2018               40000          10000                3.000000
           2019              100000          50000                1.000000
           2020               50000          25000                1.000000
```

Answer (score 3):

just specify `periods=-1` and pick column `[actual_cost]` as follows:

```
df['actual_budget_pct_diff'] = df.pct_change(periods=-1, axis='columns',fill_method='ffill')['actual_cost']

Out[160]:
                        actual_cost  budgeted_cost  actual_budget_pct_diff
consultant fiscal_year
BAIN       2018                4000         120000               -0.966667
           2019                 500          50500               -0.990099
           2020                1000         100000               -0.990000
EY         2018             1000000          20000               49.000000
           2019              500000          10000               49.000000
           2020              100000          10000                9.000000
KPMG       2018               40000          10000                3.000000
           2019              100000          50000                1.000000
           2020               50000          25000                1.000000
```

Comment: I read the documentation, but wasn't exactly sure still what exactly the periods = -1 does?

Comment: it is shift-left 1 instead of shift-right 1 as default.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the `df.pct_change` function on another dataframe with reordered columns easily, without changing the columns of `df` itself.

```
df['actual_budget_pct_diff'] = df[['budgeted_cost', 'actual_cost']].pct_change(axis='columns', fill_method='ffill')['actual_cost']
```

Note, that `df[['budgeted_cost', 'actual_cost']]` is a new dataframe which doesn't affect the column order of original dataframe `df`. Thus, the order of `df` is still preserved as required:

```
                        actual_cost  budgeted_cost  actual_budget_pct_diff
consultant fiscal_year                                                    
BAIN       2018                4000         120000               -0.966667
           2019                 500          50500               -0.990099
           2020                1000         100000               -0.990000
EY         2018             1000000          20000               49.000000
           2019              500000          10000               49.000000
           2020              100000          10000                9.000000
KPMG       2018               40000          10000                3.000000
           2019              100000          50000                1.000000
           2020               50000          25000                1.000000
```